# Can I Reuse Array Variables With Changed length?

Tags: java, arrays

Can I Use Array Variables With Changed Length Each Time 
like

```
int [] primes = new int[6];
...
primes = new int[4];
```

Can I Use Prime Again Like I Did Above ? Is It Possible ? If Not Can You Give Me Reason Thanks .

Comment: You have an IDE, why don't you test it?

Comment: its possible, but depends on your requirement. Say your 1st array was of length 6 and had 6 elements (user data). Now you want to convert it into an array of size 4, So how willing are you to risk the loss of two elements.

Comment: It's a different array. Arrays have a fixed length at creation time. But yes, you can throw away six ints to create a new array that can hold four ints.

Comment: You could have trivially answered this question yourself in 3 minutes in your Java IDE.

Answer (score 1):

You are not reusing the same array, but creating new instances of array object. The java array object has a fixed length (`final int`), so it's impossible to change the length of an array after instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Some explanation to your question.
You can run the following code and will get better understanding.
As java can't get the address, so here using hashcode to show the object address.

```
int[] prime = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
System.out.println(Arrays.hashCode(prime));
System.out.println("prime[0]="+prime[0]);

prime = new int[]{4,3,2,1,0};
System.out.println(Arrays.hashCode(prime));
System.out.println("prime[0]="+prime[0]);


Output like this:
    955331
    prime[0]=1
    1045631
    prime[0]=4
```

Answer (score 0):

**Array can not be resized once memory is being allocated as array get a contiguous memory block.**

```
   int arr[] = new int[3];
```

[image]

Once memory space is hold, resizing the array is not possible as next contiguous memory block may not be available. You can either create a new array and shift all the elements of previous array to the new array with different size.

I would recommend using [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for dynamic array. If you get in any such situation.

Answer (score 0):

## Two separate arrays

You are *not* changing the length of the array. You are creating a second array, separate and distinct from the first.

You created two arrays but used only a single reference variable (`primes`) to track them. When you assigned the second array to `primes`, the first was forgotten. The first array is still floating around in memory, a candidate for eventual [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) if no other reference points to it.

## `ArrayList`

If you want resizing, use a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementation such as [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) rather than a mere array. You’ll need to store objects ([`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)) rather than primitives (`int`). The [auto-boxing  feature in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) can mask the difference.

```
int initialCapacity = 6 ;
ArrayList< Integer > primes = new ArrayList<>( initialCapacity ) ;
primes.add( 7 ) ;  // The primitive `int` 7 literal is automatically converted via autoboxing to be an `Integer` Object.
```

The `ArrayList` automatically grows its capacity as needed to store additional items.

If you wish to free up extra capacity not allocated to hold any objects, call `ArrayList::trimToSize()`.